# Trying to use my project with external opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm attaching some external libraries to my project in C++.
These libraries make use of the opencv2 libraries.

I already added the opencv2 include files to my c/c++ properties. I also added all the relevant lib files which I googled and found to the Linker input list. (I'm running the release version, but I also tried the debug version with the "d" extension).

- opencv_core230.lib
- opencv_highgui230.lib
- opencv_objdetect230.lib
- opencv_imgproc230.lib
- opencv_ml230.lib
- opencv_legacy230.lib
- opencv_video230.lib

I'm getting these 4 annoying linking problems regarding the `setSVMDetector@HOGDescriptor`.
I looked everywhere for a solution and couldn't find one.; no one really uses the setSVM function in the external program.

Here are the linking problems:

```
Error   14  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall cv::HOGDescriptor::setSVMDetector(class cv::_InputArray const &)" (?setSVMDetector@HOGDescriptor@cv@@UAEXABV_InputArray@2@@Z)    C:\Users\idan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\GraspTestingTool\GraspTestingTool\GraspTestingTool.obj   GraspTestingTool

Error   15  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall cv::HOGDescriptor::setSVMDetector(class cv::_InputArray const &)" (?setSVMDetector@HOGDescriptor@cv@@UAEXABV_InputArray@2@@Z)    C:\Users\idan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\GraspTestingTool\GraspTestingTool\htmlGenerator.obj  GraspTestingTool

Error   16  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall cv::HOGDescriptor::setSVMDetector(class cv::_InputArray const &)" (?setSVMDetector@HOGDescriptor@cv@@UAEXABV_InputArray@2@@Z)    C:\Users\idan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\GraspTestingTool\GraspTestingTool\sequenceTests.obj  GraspTestingTool

Error   17  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall cv::HOGDescriptor::setSVMDetector(class cv::_InputArray const &)" (?setSVMDetector@HOGDescriptor@cv@@UAEXABV_InputArray@2@@Z)    C:\Users\idan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\GraspTestingTool\GraspTestingTool\Utilities.obj  GraspTestingTool
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: The only `HOGDescriptor` I see in `cv` is in `gpu` module [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/object_detection.html?#gpu-hogdescriptor)

Comment: yeah, but then the lib: "opencv_objdetect230.lib" is supposed to cover it, right?
Or should I include another lib?
Thanks,
Idan.

Comment: No. the gpu module is in `opencv_gpu230.lib`.

Comment: I added the lib, but I'm still getting this linking error for each class that I have: 

Error 5 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall cv::HOGDescriptor::setSVMDetector(class cv::_InputArray const &)" (?setSVMDetector@HOGDescriptor@cv@@UAEXABV_InputArray@2@@Z) C:\Users\idan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\GraspTestingTool\GraspTestingTool\GraspTestingTool.obj GraspTestingTool

Comment: There must be some problems with opencv docs site. I did not find any `cv::HOGDescriptor` there, but apparently there is one, i've checked the code and it's there. (note that `opencv_gpu` handles `gpu::HOCDescriptor`.) I've tested a trivial code with `opencv_objdetect` 2.4.2 and it compiled without a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Error is due to not adding specifice library in debug or releas mode.
    use 32 bit or 64 library depending on your target machine 
    Add respective library of opencv in release mode -

```
opencv_core242.lib opencv_highgui242.lib opencv_imgproc242.lib opencv_ml242.lib   
opencv_legacy242.lib opencv_video242.lib
```

OR If you want run program in debug mode then 
    use debug lib of opencv

```
opencv_core220d.lib
opencv_highgui220d.lib
opencv_video220d.lib
opencv_ml220d.lib
opencv_legacy220d.lib
opencv_imgproc220d.lib


opencv_objdetect242.lib

C:\opencv\build\x86\vc10\lib
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the library file "opencv_objdetect248.lib; opencv_objdetect248d.lib;" in Project roperties-->Linker-->Input.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add opencv_objdetect library. If you using debug mode add objdetect(version)d.lib, however, if you release mode add objdetect(version).lib